# iptable rules to allow downloading stuff while default policy is on DROP

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ip

I was trying to install bind and for some reason I was getting issues most likely due to my iptable rules , I can ping google.ca anybody have any reccomndations down below are my current rulesets

```
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP


#policy
iptables -A INPUT -i lo  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo  -j ACCEPT
#pings
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
#
#allow dns  pings

iptables -I INPUT -i ens33 -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i ens37 -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -o ens33 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -o ens37 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
#
#forward chain
iptables -I FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT # go to websites
```

Comment: What do you mean by "thins"?

Comment: @Tilman my bad typo

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by "stuff"? Please try to be a bit more specific. It would be best to show an example of what you want to download, how you try to do it (Firefox? wget? Something else?) and what issue you encounter. If you get an error message please quote it verbatim. Remember people here cannot see your screen so it's very difficult for us to guess what your problem is.